# Calendar is partially hidden from <header> tag

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I'm trying to show fullcalendar on his full height,
it is an item of  tag as container, but if I set height 100% is reimain hidden. 
Sorry but I can't understard what is wrong.

[image: 2019-06-22-09h54-15.png]

Comment: You can put the debugging menu on the side and attach a screenshot to see more properties of main-content?

Comment: Anyway I see that you have the heigth at 75vh, not 100vh, and a hidden overflow

Comment: I've removed the overflow: hidden, and than calendar is visible, but the <header> is the same size of height, and the next element is in overlapping

Comment: it may be due to some of the properties of the next element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with: `removed overflow:hidden;`
And `class="overlay mt-3 align-items-center text-center"` 
in < header >